# what event is raised when a tabPage is removed from a TabControl in C#

Tags: c#, winforms, tabcontrol

What event can I handle when a tabPage is removed from a TabControl in C# WinForms, so I can hide the window, if there are no tabPages in the TabControl?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `SelectedIndexChanged` event.  Then use the `((TabControl)sender).TabCount` to determine if any tabs are left on the control.  If the count is zero, hide the control.

No matter how you accomplish grabbing the event, you'll need to do a check against the tab count to hide your control.

Answer (score 2):

Try ControlRemoved:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.controlremoved.aspx

Comment: TabControl.ControlRemoved event unfortunately fires prior to the TabPage is actually removed so the TabCount doesn't update until the event method has completed - making the method either useless or miss-named.